# Place two divs next to each other using float: left

Tags: css, css-float

I have these two divs:

```html
<div style="width:400px; height: 400px; background-color: red; float: left">my first div. width 400px</div>
<div style="width:600px; height: 400px; background-color: green; ">my second div. width 600px</div>
```

As you can see, I have floated the first one.
**The problem**: I expected the second to be placed on the right of the first one, but no..

Since having two paragraphs this way,

```
<p style="float: left">my first paragraph</p>
<p>my second paragraph</p>
```

the second paragraph is on the right of the first one, **why it is not working in the same way for the divs**?

NOTE: I know I can use other methods to put the divs next to each other. For example adding `float: left` to the second div, but what I really want to know is why is not working just adding `float: left` to the first one as with paragraphs or `<li>`s happens.

Comment: The second one is to the right of the first one? http://i.imgur.com/Gd7epx4.png

Comment: @MichaelCoker no, the second one (green) is just behind the first one. The first one is 400px width, and the second one is 600px width.

Comment: Oh. If you give your paragraphs (or just the 2nd one) a background color, you'll see the 2nd one goes behind the 1st one, too. If you `float: left` the 1st one, the 2nd element doesn't wrap around the 1st one - the **inline content** in the 2nd one wraps around the 1st one. You're seeing the same behavior. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float "The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container, **where text and inline elements will wrap around it.**"

Answer (score 0):

P tag by default have this style

```
 clear: both;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
 margin-top: 0;
```

you should be overridden
try it

```
p {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    display: block;
    background-color: green;
    margin: auto;
    clear: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the standard mode for integrating images into longer text and the text "floating around" the image: The image gets a float (left or right), the text does not, the result is an image inside one or several paragraphs of text - a very useful principle:

```css
img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/360x240/0af"/>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>

<p>Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.</p>

<p>Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi.</p>

<p>Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
```